# Facebook is showing "Database Error" when I share a link to a post to my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I am using ifttt.com to automatically post my wordpress blog posts to facebook.
But when it posts to facebook everything else is fine it gives correct link as well but says "database error" in place of post title. See the below image:
The red circle shows the problem.
[image: it shows database error instead of post title]

Is there any problem with my wordpress blog or ifttt.com recipe configuration.
My recipe is https://ifttt.com/recipes/252982-rss-feed-to-facebook

Answer (score 0):

When I run one of your blog articles through the [facebook URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) I get a notice that: "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

I'm not sure why that would be you the database error notice, but it's at least a start for eliminating a variable from your equation.

There are also [other people with similar issues](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-error-when-sharing-to-facebook) being resolved by making the facebook debugger happy.